# how send aes encrypted document as a response in django

Tags: python, django, web, aes

I am making a web app using Django I want to send some encrypted file to the user when he tries to click on the button.
I am using

```
 return FileResponse(open("media/book/a_enc.pdf" , 'rb'))
```

but it is giving me an internal server error. how can I send an encrypted file to a user in django